# Compare lists Python

Tags: python, list, csv, compare

I have a compared two CSV files and have data like this (I'm not sure if these are called lists or list of lists or something else):

from file1: x =

```
['BDCA0', '01', '25', 'A']
['PPTR', '02', '14', 'A']
['ABCD1', '07', '14', 'A']
```

from file2: y =

```
['ABCD1', '00', '4', 'A']
['BDCA0', '04', '25', 'A']
['PPTR', '02', '14', 'A']
```

I want to compare these two and print the differences but keep the first element unchanged. My desired output is:

```
['ABCD1', '07', '14', 'A']
['ABCD1', '00', '4', 'A']
['BDCA0', '01', '25', 'A']
['BDCA0', '04', '25', 'A']
```

I tried doing `[a for a in x if a not in y] + [a for a in y if a not in x]` but its giving me junk.

Comment: Are the rows in the same order?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Not necessarily!

Comment: So you need to sort rows first, or the first column is a key column to mach rows  from the two files?

Comment: Its not the key. I've used it as a key to match already and these are the resulted lists. I just want the differences in these lists now, keeping the first column in the output. @Marcin

Comment: And if it is the key colum: are these keys guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: If it's not the key: by which criterion should two rows be compared? Is it just the order? If it is: what if two rows with equal index do not have the same first item?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke In that case, first column can be used as the key.

Comment: @Marcin first column can be used as the key.

Comment: Is this just: `cat x y | sort | uniq`?

Answer (score 0):

There are less convoluted ways of doing this- you could, for example, create a list that's the intersection of the two lists, and then create a list comprised of only those elements not in the intersection- but this accomplishes the same goal.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from operator import itemgetter
import json

with open("x.json") as f:
    x = json.load(f)
with open("y.json") as f:
    y = json.load(f)
def diff(a, b):
   return [aa for aa in a if aa not in b]
def notintersect(a,b):
   return sorted(diff(a,b) + diff(b,a), key=itemgetter(0))

for row in notintersect(x,y):
   print"[",
   sep=''
   for col in row:
      print sep + repr(str(col)),
      sep=','
   print ']'
```

output:

```
[ 'ABCD1' ,'07' ,'14' ,'A' ]
[ 'ABCD1' ,'00' ,'4' ,'A' ]
[ 'BDCA0' ,'01' ,'25' ,'A' ]
[ 'BDCA0' ,'04' ,'25' ,'A' ]
```

To get the data out of the files into a usable format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

(
    read LINE
    echo "[$LINE" | tr "'" '"'
    while read LINE
    do
      echo ",$LINE"| tr "'" '"'
    done
    echo "]"
) < "$1" > "$1.json"
```

(You also need to manually remove that "header" comment, but assuming that's the only comment, that's not much overhead.This also assumes that your data doesn't contain any single or double quotes, which- based on the example data you gave- seemed like a fair assumption.)

Comment: My lists are not structured like this. They are just the way I posted in question and your answer is not working for my lists :(

Comment: Oh... So, you're files actually contain the square brackets and single quotes? I don't think they count as CSV in that case. I'd just kind of assumed you'd already loaded them. :P

Comment: Okay, well, I have a hack that'd work for your case. Gimme a sec.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at using pandas. It seems as a good match to what you are trying to do. For example,

```
import pandas as pd


x1 = [['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4'],
['ABCD1', '07', '14', 'A'],
['BDCA0', '01', '25', 'A'],
['PPTR', '02', '14', 'A']]

x2 = [['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4'],
['ABCD1', '00', '4', 'A'],
['BDCA0', '04', '25', 'A'],
['PPTR', '02', '14', 'A']]




df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1[1:], columns=x1[0]).set_index('h1')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(x2[1:], columns=x2[0]).set_index('h1')

print(df1[df1!=df2])
print(df2[df1!=df2])


        h2   h3   h4
h1                  
ABCD1   07   14  NaN
BDCA0   01  NaN  NaN
PPTR   NaN  NaN  NaN
        h2   h3   h4
h1                  
ABCD1   00    4  NaN
BDCA0   04  NaN  NaN
PPTR   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Yes, I know it does not match your exactly your output, because I'm not sure how you exactly compare the rows. But i think that using pandas could be useful, especially if you have to do similar things a lot.

Comment: What if we don't have header row?

Comment: Than pandas will make its own as numbers of columns, e.g. 0,1,2,3. The same for key column (i.e. index).

Comment: How would this line change? `df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1[1:], columns=x1[0]).set_index('h1')`

Comment: If you dont want any custom header or index, than just do df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1)

Comment: I need index but some times I don't have header.

Comment: If you dont have header, you can always provide it manually, e.g. `pd.DataFrame(x1[1:], columns=[''h1,'h2', 'h3', 'h4'])`, or remove it when you have it, to have dateframes of the same structure/layout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can be sure that you have the same first elements in each list, but if you do (and you can spare the memory to duplicate the data in a pair of new data structures), dictionaries could work well for you:

```
x = [
     ['BDCA0', '01', '25', 'A'],
     ['PPTR', '02', '14', 'A'],
     ['ABCD1', '07', '14', 'A']
    ]

y = [
     ['ABCD1', '00', '4', 'A'],
     ['BDCA0', '04', '25', 'A'],
     ['PPTR', '02', '14', 'A']
    ]

dx = dict([(xx[0], xx[1:]) for xx in x])
dy = dict([(yy[0], yy[1:]) for yy in y])

for k, v in dx.items():
    if v != dy[k]:
        print [k] + v
        print [k] + dy[k]
```

gives:

```
['ABCD1', '07', '14', 'A']
['ABCD1', '00', '4', 'A']
['BDCA0', '01', '25', 'A']
['BDCA0', '04', '25', 'A']
```